# What fonts are used in this paper?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm looking for both the text font and the math font used in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03797.pdf). I'm posting a screenshot below. What fonts are they and where can I get them to use in LaTeX?

[image]